# What would be the period of a Foucault pendulum placed at the pole of the Moon?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moon

How long does it take the Moon to rotate about itself once?
There are two answers to this, the sidereal period and the synodic period.

Sidereal period would be the quick answer to the question here, but synodic period feels like a more fundamental period for the Moon.

I have trouble accepting the notion of an absolute rotational speed, with respect to what?

Comment: For big bodies like the Earth and Moon, the deviation from sphericity is a measure of the (true) rotation. In the case of the Earth, if not rotating it would be a perfect sphere, instead of an oblate spheroid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the poles [Foucault pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum) swings in a plane that is fixed with respect to the distant stars and galaxies. As such, on the Moon its plane will appear to move with a period of one *sidereal* month.

The idea of having an absolute reference frame for rotation (even though we know there is no absolute reference frame for linear motion) puzzled Einstein, who named it [Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle) after Austrian physicist and philosopher [Ernst Mach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach).

Comment: I recommend editing this answer to include the following information: While it is the case that the plane of swing of a *polar* Foucault pendulum does not rotate with respect to inertial space, that property does not extend to non-polar Foucault pendulums. One way to see that is as follows: At the latitude of Paris the Foucault cycle has a period of 32 hours. Hence, at the latitude of Paris, when a Foucault pendulum is started in north-south direction, after 24 hours (hence with the Earth back in the original orientation), the plane of swing has has turned to east-west. [continuing]

Comment: [Continued] It is tempting to assume that a Foucault pendulum cannot exchange momentum with its basis. But the example of the Foucault pendulum with 32 hour period leaves no room for doubt. Start with north-south oscillation, and one sidereal day later, with the Earth back in the same orientation: plane of swing is in east-west orientation. That is a change of momentum of the pendulum bob.

Answer (score 1):

The polar Foucault pendulum has already been addressed in the answer by gandalf61, in this answer I want to go into the question about reference of angular velocity.

I will address that in terms of the relation between linear mechanics and angular mechanics.

In linear mechanics we have the following three entities:
-Position
-Velocity
-Acceleration

I like to think of the relation between the three of them as a *cascading* pattern.
-Velocity: the derivative of *position* with respect to time
-Acceleration: the derivative of *velocity* with respect to time

$F=ma$ expresses the universal law of inertia.

We assume that Inertia is the same everywhere.
(For the sake of simplicity I discuss the case such that any source of gravitational attraction is so far away that there is negligable gravitational effect. For instance, we can place this thought demonstration in intergalactic space.)

If inertia would change randomly from moment to moment, and from location to location, then there would not be any reference at all.

However, we have abundant reason to assume that inertia is perfectly uniform. That very uniformity allows inertia to serve as a *universal reference* of acceleration.

An Inertial Measurement Unit (IMU) uses inertia as reference of acceleration.

By integrating acceleration it is possible to use an IMU as a reference of *position*.

Let's take the following thought demonstration: two spaceships are initially co-moving. At some point in time they start propulsion to each move on a separate journey. Both spaceships use IMU's to keep track of their current position relative to the point of departure.

So both spaceships keep logs of the direction of travel and the magnitude of acceleration. The velocity (as function of time) can be reconstructed by integrating the acceleration history. With the velocity vector as a function of time known: the position (as a function of time) can be reconstructed by integrating the velocity history.

The two spaceships can agree to rejoin at some future point in time. Both spaceships can always reconstruct their current position relative to the starting point, so they can alway plot a course back to it.

The fact that the spaceships can rejoin underlines that there is a *universal reference*. It is the uniformity of inertia that is providing that reference.

For emphasis I repreat:
The fact that inertia is *uniform thoughout space* is what allows it to be used as a reference of position.

That does not quite amount to an absolute reference of position; the choice of zero point of the coordinate system is arbitrary. The point is: it still allows navigation back to a starting point.

(This property of allowing-navigation-back-to-the-starting point is equally valid in the context of special relativity. Of course, in Minkowski spacetime plotting the course is a more demanding task. We assume all crew members of the spaceships are experts in application of special relativity, otherwise the thought demonstration would be useless.)

When you spin up a gyroscope the motion of the gyro wheel is in the realm of *accelerated motion*. The spinning gyro wheel is subject to centripetal force, provided by the structural integrity of the gyro wheel. The centripetal acceleration of the gyrowheel encounters in all directions *the same inertia*.

To change the orientation of the spin axis of the gyro wheel a force is required . For a given rate of change of spin axis orientation: the faster the rate of spin, the larger the force required to cause that particular rate of change of spin axis orientation.